How to show the function $\chi_{[0,f(x)]}(t)$ is product measurable?
Background:Let $(E,\mathcal A)$ be a measurable space and let $\mu$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure on $(E,A)$.Let $f:E\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}_+$ be a nonnegative measurable function.
i am trying to show that:
$$\int_Ef \mathrm{d}\mu=\int_0^\infty\mu(\{x\in E:f(x)\geq t\}) \mathrm{d}t$$
("$dt$" means Lebesgue measure)i know that:$$\int_Ef d\mu=\int_E\big(\int_{\mathbb R}\chi_{[0,f(x)]}(t)dt\big)\mu(dx)$$ So I want to use The Fubini Theorems.
Question:How can i check that$$g:E\times \mathbb R\to \mathbb R,g(x,t)=\chi_{[0,f(x)]}(t)$$ is a $\mathcal A\otimes \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ measurable function?
(Before using Fubini Theorems,we need to check $g(x,t)$ is product measurable)
My attempt to the question:$$C:=\{(x,t)\in E\times \mathbb R:0\le t\le f(x)\}\Rightarrow g(x,t)=\chi_C(x,t)$$Thus,only need to check that $C\in\mathcal A\otimes \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$,but i am stuck here.

Write $g$ as $$\begin{aligned}g(x,t)&=\chi_{\{0\le \pi_2\le(f\circ\pi_1)\}}(x,t)\\&=\chi_{\{0\le \pi_2\}}(x,t)\chi_{\{(f\circ\pi_1)-\pi_2\ge 0\}}(x,t).\end{aligned}$$
You now have a product of indicator functions of product measurable sets (measurable because they are preimages of product measurable functions $\pi_2$ and $(f\circ\pi_1)-\pi_2$).

Hints: Let $f_n(x)=\frac {i+1}{2^{n}}$ if $\frac i {2^{n}} \le f(x) <\frac {i+1} {2^{n}}$, $i=0,1,2...$. Check that $f_n$ is measurable and $f_n(x)$ decreases to $f(x)$ for each $x$. Note that $t \le f(x)$ iff $t \le f_n(x)$ for each $n$. Let $g_n(x)=\chi_{[0,f_n(x)]}(t)$. Then $g_n(x) \to g(x)$ for each $x$. It is fairly easy to see that $g_n$ is $A\otimes \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ measurable.
